# Duda sobre el orden de precedencia de los operadores C++

Tags: c++, operador

Me surgió una duda al leer sobre el orden de precedencia en el libro: "El lenguaje de programación C++" (2da edición, Bjarne Stroustrup, 1991) en las páginas 95 y 96 de mi versión en español.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque "a+b*c" significa "a+(b*c)".
Dice que es porque: "* tiene mayor precedencia que +"

Pero eso sería cierto si el "*" en la operación "a+b*c" fuera una indirección, ya que ahí sí que tendría mayor precedencia (esta en un recuadro superior) y al ser un operador unario la asociatividad sería de derecha a izquierda. Pero en la operación "a+b*c" el "*" tiene pinta de ser un operador de multiplicación, que por lo tanto tendría la misma precedencia que el + (están en el mismo recuadro)

Dice: "Cada recuadro contiene operadores con la misma precedencia. Un operador tiene mayor precedencia que los de recuadros inferiores". Y además el * de multiplicación es un operador binario (que toma dos operandos) y por tanto su asociatividad es de izquierda a derecha, no de derecha a izquierda como el * unario (indirección)
Entonces por lo que dice el libro inferiría que "a+b*c" es "(a+b)*c" no "a+(b*c)"

Por probar seguí la misma lógica con "20+15/3". El "/" definitivamente aparece en el mismo recuadro que "+", no hay otro operador (hasta donde sé) que sea "/" unario. Entonces tengo una expresión con todos operadores binarios (que toman dos operandos) y que están en el mismo recuadro. Y por ello esperaría que: "20+15/3" sea "(20+15)/3", pero cuando lo voy a probar en C++ uno me da 25 y el otro 11.
¿Que estoy entendiendo mal del libro?

Comment: Espero que esta página te sea de ayuda: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/cpp-built-in-operators-precedence-and-associativity?view=msvc-170.

Comment: La precedencia para operadores aritméticos coincide con la de matemática.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apostaría que tiene un error de impresión, fíjate que entre `residuo` y `sumar`  hay un gran espacio, seguramente ahí va una línea separando los grupo 5 (multiplicación, división y residuo) con el grupo 6 (suma y resta) que sería lo correcto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Aquí una [Tabla de prioridad y asociatividad](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/cpp-built-in-operators-precedence-and-associativity?view=msvc-170) completa, separadas por grupos

| Descripción del operador | Operador | Alternativa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Precedencia de grupo 1, sin asociatividad** |  |  |
| Resolución de ámbito | `::` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 2, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Selección de miembro (objeto o puntero) | `.` o `->` |  |
| Subíndice de matriz | `[]` |  |
| Llamada a función | `()` |  |
| Incremento de postfijo | `++` |  |
| Decremento de postfijo | `--` |  |
| Nombre de tipo | `typeid` |  |
| Conversión de tipos constante | `const_cast` |  |
| Conversión de tipos dinámica | `dynamic_cast` |  |
| Conversión de tipos reinterpretada | `reinterpret_cast` |  |
| Conversión de tipos estática | `static_cast` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 3, asociatividad de derecha a izquierda** |  |  |
| Tamaño de objeto o tipo | `sizeof` |  |
| Incremento de prefijo | `++` |  |
| Decremento de prefijo | `--` |  |
| Complemento a uno | `~` | **`compl`** |
| NOT lógico | `!` | **`not`** |
| Negación unaria | `-` |  |
| Suma unaria | `+` |  |
| Dirección de | `&` |  |
| Direccionamiento indirecto | `*` |  |
| Crear objeto | `new` |  |
| Destruir objeto | `delete` |  |
| Conversión | `()` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 4, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Puntero a miembro (objetos o punteros) | `.*` o `->*` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 5, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Multiplicación | `*` |  |
| División | `/` |  |
| Módulo | `%` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 6, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Suma | `+` |  |
| Resta | `-` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 7, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Desplazamiento a la izquierda | `<<` |  |
| Desplazamiento a la derecha | `>>` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 8, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Menor que | `<` |  |
| Mayor que | `>` |  |
| Menor o igual que | `<=` |  |
| Mayor o igual que | `>=` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 9, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Igualdad | `==` |  |
| Desigualdad | `!=` | **`not_eq`** |
| **Precedencia de grupo 10 asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| AND bit a bit | `&` | **`bitand`** |
| **Precedencia de grupo 11, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| OR exclusivo bit a bit | `^` | **`xor`** |
| **Precedencia de grupo 12, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| OR inclusivo bit a bit | `\|` | **`bitor`** |
| **Precedencia de grupo 13, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Y lógico | `&&` | **`and`** |
| **Precedencia de grupo 14, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| O lógico | `\|\|` | **`or`** |
| **Precedencia de grupo 15, asociatividad de derecha a izquierda** |  |  |
| Condicional | `? :` |  |
| Cesión | `=` |  |
| Asignación y multiplicación | `*=` |  |
| Asignación y división | `/=` |  |
| Asignación y módulo | `%=` |  |
| Asignación y suma | `+=` |  |
| Asignación y resta | `-=` |  |
| Asignación y desplazamiento a la izquierda | `<<=` |  |
| Asignación y desplazamiento a la derecha | `>>=` |  |
| Asignación AND bit a bit | `&=` | **`and_eq`** |
| Asignación y OR inclusivo bit a bit | `\|=` | **`or_eq`** |
| Asignación OR exclusivo bit a bit | `^=` | **`xor_eq`** |
| Expresión Throw | `throw` |  |
| **Precedencia de grupo 16, asociatividad de izquierda a derecha** |  |  |
| Coma | , |  |

Comment: Aaaah, es verdad. No lo había notado. Probablemente sea eso que decís. Me voy a fijar más tarde si encuentro la misma versión del libro en inglés para confirmar lo que me estás diciendo. Pero tiene toda la pinta. Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Uh, me acabo de dar cuenta de esto. ¿Pero puede ser que la tabla tenga otro error más ?. Porque aparece en la tabla del libro en el grupo de precedencia 2 el "." (selección de miembro) pero el "++" aparece en el grupo de precedencia 3. Mientras que en lo que enviaste el "." y "++" aparecen en el grupo de precedencia 2.

Comment: Incluso otra cuestión más, en el libro dice que los operadores unarios son asociativos de derecha a izquierda. Por tanto me desconcierta que ello no coincide con lo que dice en este otro lugar: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence . Ahí muestra que el ++ y -- posfijo tienen asociatividad de izquierda a derecha ? Pero si son operadores unarios!
¿ Que está pasando ?

Comment: Nunca hay que descartar errores en los libros académicos (por eso tienen re ediciones) y ni Stroustrup es infalible. Luego tienes que el traductor puede que haya cometido un error. Lo mejor en ese caso es ir a la fuente actualiza. Por ejemplo si alguien busca por `github "The C++ Programming Language"` podría  encontrar una versión PDF del libro en ingles y ver que en la página 255 hay cambios significativos a la páginas que tu has mostrado en tu pregunta.  Y me parece que estos cambios resuelven tus inquetudes

Comment: Sí, definitivamente lo que tengo en mi libro difiere de lo que dice en la versión actualizada del mismo. Me voy a fiar de la versión actualizada en inglés.

Comment: Hasta donde estoy viendo parece que la tabla de precedencia de operadores en la 3era y 4ta edición tampoco coinciden. Por ejemplo en la tercera edición la selección de miembro object.member y el post incremento figuran en el mismo grupo de precedencia. Pero en la 4ta edición object.member esta en un grupo de precedencia pero ++ (post incremento) figura en otro !
Me resulta llamativo, ¿puede ser que a medida que paso el tiempo la precedencia de los operadores fue cambiando en C++ ? ¿ Y que lo de mi libro entonces no sea un error si no que la precedencia de operadores era así en 1991?

Comment: Puede ser, si buscas "Refining Expression Evaluation Order for Idiomatic C++" te vas a dar cuenta que hasta por lo menos el 2016 se seguía discutiendo estas cosas (y un ejemplo de ese libro es una de las causas). Yo te aconsejo que formules una nueva pregunta (a mi me parece que lo vale), y muestres todos los antecedentes que tienes.  Como te dije en otro comentario, yo C++ lo vi hace demasiados años y nunca tan en profundidad como tu, entonces por mucho que me gustaría ayudarte, no puedo. Ahora si quieres javascript y C#, pfff lo que quieras.

Comment: Ok,estoy leyendo eso que dijiste "Refining Expression Evaluation Order for Idiomatic C++", pero habla (como dice el título) del orden de evaluación de las subexpresiones. Que es un tema diferente al de la precedencia y asociatividad de operadores. De hecho lo que dice mi libro coincide con como arranca el documento ese: "In a nutshell, given
an expression such as f(a, b, c), the order in which the sub-expressions f, a, b, c (which are of arbitrary
shapes) are evaluated is left unspecified by the standard.".
Pero sí, me parece que voy a abrir una nueva pregunta al respecto porque lo merece.